# Some '<' tags within a PHP SOAP response displaying as HTML '&lt;' entities

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am getting some data from a Web Service using PHP SOAP. The data I receive from the Soap Client using `__getLastResponse` appears to be a SOAP envelope around the relevant XML data, which is fine as I am then planning on turning this into a `SimpleXMLElement` to extract the data.

The problem is that the data looks correct until it hits a certain `<records>` tag, after which it replaces all `<` tags with `&lt;`.

This is what the data looks like when I `print_r` it (this is just a small example of the full data):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:searchResponse xmlns:ns2="http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com"><return><queryId>1</queryId><recordsFound>16492</recordsFound><recordsSearched>38802522</recordsSearched><records>&lt;records xmlns="http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord">
&lt;REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">&lt;UID>WOS:000257367300002&lt;/UID>&lt;static_data>&lt;summary>&lt;EWUID>&lt;WUID coll_id="WOS">&lt;/WUID>&lt;edition value="WOS.SCI">&lt;/edition>&lt;/EWUID>&lt;pub_info issue="8" pubtype="Journal" sortdate="2008-07-01" has_abstract="Y" coverdate="JUL 2008" pubmonth="JUL" vol="17" pubyear="2008">&lt;page end="1820" page_count="16" begin="1805">1805-1820&lt;/page>&lt;/pub_info>&lt;titles count="6"&gt;&lt;title type="source">BIODIVERSITY AND CONSERVATION&lt;/title>...etc...&lt;/static_data>&lt;dynamic_data>&lt;citation_related>&lt;tc_list>&lt;silo_tc local_count="16" coll_id="WOS">&lt;/silo_tc>&lt;/tc_list>&lt;/citation_related>&lt;cluster_related>&lt;identifiers>&lt;identifier value="0960-3115" type="issn">&lt;/identifier>&lt;identifier value="10.1007/s10531-007-9267-2" type="doi">&lt;/identifier>&lt;identifier value="10.1007/s10531-007-9267-2" type="xref_doi">&lt;/identifier>&lt;/identifiers>&lt;/cluster_related>&lt;/dynamic_data>&lt;/REC>
&lt;/records></records></return></ns2:searchResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Why are the opening tags displaying correctly until it gets to the second `<records>` tag? After that it replaces them with `&lt;` until it reaches the closing `</records>` tag, when it carries on displaying the opening tags correctly. It doesn't affect the closing tags or the quotation marks which is strange.

Is this something to do with `CDATA`? That's all I can think of although it doesn't state that there is a block of `CDATA` anywhere...

Thanks.

Comment: Is this web service public? Can you post the url to do some testing?

Comment: Not public, I'm afraid, it's a paid for service for Web of Science to retrieve journals and papers

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not with print_r? Have you tried to turn it into SimpleXMLElement object? Try that, and let's see if you have an error.

Comment: It won't let me turn it into a SimpleXMLElement object as it doesn't class it as well-formed XML due to the `&lt;` elements. The variables I have are `$string` which is the data listed above, which is a subset of another variable `$search_client` which is the Soap Client object returned from the SOAP response. I'm getting the `$string` from `$search_client->__getLastResponse()`.

Comment: `<records>&lt;records`. Is this normal? A records tag, having a child with the same tag?

Comment: Yeah I thought it was weird but that's what the Web Service returns. They determine the XML layout so it's correct according to their API. Obviously it should be `<records><records...>` but that incorrect HTML markup is the problem I'm having. Have been trying to extract the XML data from the SOAP envelope but with no success so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, don't know if this would be the "good" soluition, but at least it works:

```
$xmlP = html_entity_decode($client->__getLastResponse());
```

This is to decode the html entities back to html. The < and > that already exists in the string correctly, are kept the same.

Hope this helps to anyone